# Adding circle to path using getPointAtLength() is shifted

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I would add dot to a path dynamically

here's my code

```
const cir1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
let path= document.getElementById('path9');

this.getPath=path;
let g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

let pt = path.getPointAtLength('60');
g.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${pt.x},${pt.y})`);
g.appendChild(cir1)
cir1.setAttribute('r', '3');
cir1.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
cir1.setAttribute('id','123');
let svg =document.getElementById('Calque_1');
svg.appendChild(g)
```

Actually dot is shifted and not on the path I can't figure why.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-resizing-fiypoa?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is itself transformed. When you get the co-ordinates they are in the co-ordinate system of the path. You can adjust for that by adding the path's transform e.g.

```
const cir1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
let path= document.getElementById('path9');

this.getPath=path;
let g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

let pt = path.getPointAtLength('60');
let path_transform = path.getAttribute('transform');
g.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${pt.x},${pt.y}) ${path_transform}`);
g.appendChild(cir1)
cir1.setAttribute('r', '3');
cir1.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
cir1.setAttribute('id','123');
let svg =document.getElementById('Calque_1');
svg.appendChild(g)
```

Comment: actually nothing is printed ( no circle )

Comment: a) I see a circle in the wrong place without the change and b) in the right place with the change